# Proving the range of an Integral

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

> Show that
>   $$\frac{\pi}3\le\iint_D \frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}}\le \pi$$ 
>   where $D$ is the unit disk at origin.

I believe I need to find two functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ that are are bounds $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}}$ in the unit disk.

I found $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=g(x,y)$$
I get $$\iint_Dg(x,y)dxdy= 2\pi$$

I am not sure how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $(x,y)\in D$ then
$$1=d((0,1),(0,2))\leq d((x,y),(0,2))=\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}\leq d((0,-1),(0,2))=3.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{\pi}3=\iint_D \frac{1}{3}dxdy\le\iint_D \frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}}\le \iint_D 1dxdy=\pi.$$

Comment: You make it look so easy that it baffles me. :)